# PDO->exec Returning int(0) or Null

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to determine if a user is created in the database. PDO is returning int(0) or null.

The code looks something like this:

```
if( $dbh->exec( "CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'" ) )
    echo "User Created";
else
    echo "User could not be created";
```

If the user is created, it will output "User could not be created".  And if the user is already in the database, then the script will not output anything.

However, changing to

```
if( $dbh->exec( "CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'" ) === 0 )
    echo "User Created";
else
    echo "User could not be created";
```

Will result in "User Created" if the user is created, and no output if the user was already created in the database.

Why is this?  Or more importantly, how can I check if a user was successfully created?  Should I be relying on a return of int(0) on success and NULL on failure?  Since it is not documented, I'm worried that doing this may result in problems in the future.

Thanks!

-- The reason I am needing to check if a user was created, is because I am creating a user and database.  I don't want to create the database if the user cannot be created.  Also, if the script runs into a problem and can't complete the tasks, I want to undo the tasks that were performed previously.  Unfortunately PDO transactions don't work with creating new users and databases, they always auto commit.

Comment: To quickly recap the answer below.

PDO returns int(0) on success because the event was successful, but no rows in the database were affected.

PDO throws an exception on failure, and so that's why the else statement was not being executed.


Better solution:

try{
$dbh->exec("CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' );
}
catch( Exception $e )  // or PDOException
{
}

(Obviously prepared statements are the way to go here too.  I just didn't use them for brevity's sake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns the number of affected rows (int), not a boolean value depending on how the statement was executed. For example, a return value of `0` indicates no changes.

Comment: In PHP, int (0) and NULL are actually not the same. A value of int (0) explicitly means no changed rows, while the statement was executed successfully. However, a value of NULL may indicate a problem with the query.

Comment: Thanks Tacticus.  So it's returning int(0) because no "rows" were affected, however, the query was successful.  And NULL because the query was unsuccessful?

Comment: Exactly. When adding a new row, one should note that actually no (existing) rows are affected.

Comment: Just realized that it is throwing an Exception if the user already exists -- which is perfect.  That's why the else statement is not being executed.